# Изменить свойство CSS, если внутри есть определенный символ

Tags: css

Можно ли на чистом  `css` придать блоку `display none`, если в нём только число 0 и ничего более? То есть аналог `empty`, но для строковой проверки.

Answer (score 2):

С небольшим извратом используя атрибут data-value="0"

```css
p[data-value="0"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p data-value="0">0</p>
<p data-value="1">1</p>
<p data-value="0">0</p>
<p data-value="2">2</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

На чистом CSS данное решение воплотить в жизнь нельзя, так как стандарты CSS не предоставляют функционала для доступа к содержимому HTML-элементов по типу JS атрибута innerHTML.